# WP Как создать новые колонки таблицы в базе данных?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Создаю плагин Wordpress, который после активации должен к стандартной таблице `wp_posts` добавить две колонки `positive_users_reaction` и `negative_users_reaction`. В ячейках этих колонок хочу складывать id пользователей которые положительно/негативно оценили каждый пост. Вот код.

```
function create_rows()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

            $table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'posts';
            $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
            $sql = "ALTER TABLE {$table_name}
            (ADD COLUMN 
             positive_users_reaction TEXT NOT NULL AFTER comment_count,
             negative_users_reaction TEXT NOT NULL AFTER positive_users_reaction);
            {$charset_collate}";
            dbDelta($sql);

            $wpdb->insert(
                $table_name,
                    array(
                        'positive_users_reaction' => [],
                        'negative_users_reaction' => [],
                    )
                );
        }

        create_rows();
```

Подскажите, почему оно ничего не создает и не назначает скобки объекта по умолчанию (Ведь это же правильный стартовый шаблон если надо получать array)? Как это поправить что б создавало две колонки?

Comment: Никогда не трогай родные таблицы!

Comment: Вопрос немного не о том. Мне нужна помощь в том, что бы добавить колонки.

Comment: Не нужно добавлять колонки в стандартные таблицы!!! Ты совершаешь [ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). Причем тут - катастрофическую.  О чём и я тебе  и в комментах к ответу говорят. (Ты столько времени занимаешься ВП и всё никак не научишься с ним правильно работать, ужасные костыли придумываешь.)

Comment: Ok, мне нужен ответ на вопрос как добавить таблицы в колонки. Меня полностью устроит рабочий ответ с добавлением в любую кастомную таблицу. Создание контекста способствует понимания проблемы чуть дальше, но это не важно....

Comment: Добавить таблицы в колонки не возможно физически (ок, спишем это на оговорку). Но я не из тех, кто будет помогать делать неправильно, я как раз наборот, помогаю не совершить ошибки. А насчёт кастомных таблиц - это уже другой вопрос. Впрочем ответ на него, я подозреваю, будет таким же как и ниже данный.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь в одном запросе добавить второй столбец после вновь добавляемого первого и его ещё нет.
Попробуйте что-то из таких вариантов:

1. Добавлять столбцы двумя последовательными запросами.
2. Добавить оба столбца после `comment_count`.

Очень похоже на то, что ваша идея модификации `wp_posts` неправильная, для ваших целей лучше подойдёт хранение данных в `wp_postmeta`.

Comment: Попробовал, просто добавить один столбец - результат тот же. Что-то не так с синтаксисом хотя ошибок не выбрасывает. Чем хранение в `wp_postmeta` лучше ?

Comment: Ищите в отладчике ошибку. Синтаксис может зависеть от версии/диалекта SQL. Можете попробовать такой синтаксис `ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN (positive_users_reaction TEXT NOT NULL, negative_users_reaction TEXT NOT NULL) AFTER comment_count;`

Comment: `wp_postmeta` предназначен как раз для расширения стандартных данных поста. Вы не знаете, как в дальнейшем может структура таблицы `wp_posts`. Вы будете таскать  эти данные о голосах при каждом запросе к `wp_posts`, в то время как данные из `wp_postmeta` вы может загружать только тогда, когда вам это нужно. Многие плагины создают свои собственные таблицы и работают с ними - это помогает максимально изолировать ваши данные. Конечно, если вы делаете специальную быстродействующую сборку под себя и эти данные нужны вам при каждом запросе - вы можете хранить их в `wp_posts`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Что-то второй синтаксис тоже не решил проблему. Даже при создании одной колонки.

Comment: Пробуйте выполнить запрос через phpMyAdmin - он покажет ошибку в запросе

Comment: `У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'AFTER comment_count' на строке 1`

Comment: А так `ALTER TABLE users ADD positive_users_reaction TEXT NOT NULL AFTER comment_count;` ?

Comment: `Некорректное значение по умолчанию для 'post_date'`